# What is the difference between git rebase with and without the --onto option for one argument?

Tags: git

What is the difference between

```
git rebase master
```

and

```
git rebase --onto master
```

I am on my branch X which has deviated from master and I ran both these commands. However the first one required me to solve a lot of conflicts before being able to push while the second command with --onto did not have any conflicts. What explains this difference?

Comment: https://womanonrails.com/git-rebase-onto may be helpful?

Comment: Note that `git rebase --onto master` used the *upstream* setting for the current branch as the *`upstream`* argument.

Comment: `git rebase --onto master` may not have had any conflicts, but it also may not have been a very good thing to say.

Comment: Does `git rebase --onto master` really works? There should be at least 2 parameters to run `git rebase` with `--onto` parameter

Answer (score 5):

The rebase command needs to know two things:

- what to copy (which commits); and
- where to put those copies.

To *get* these two things, `git rebase` needs, at a minimum, one parameter, which [the `git rebase` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) calls *`upstream`*:

```
git rebase master
```

uses `master` as the *`upstream`* argument.

#### Sidebar: rebase works by copying as if with cherry-pick

Let's look at a typical case for rebase.  We have:

```
...--G--H--L   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K   <-- feature
```

Here, we made a feature branch (`feature`) off the `master` branch back when `master` selected commit `H`.  So then we made commits `I-J-K` to hold changes for the feature.  (The new commits do actually hold full snapshots, not just changes, but the *purpose* of our `I-J-K` was to hold specific changes.)  Then we had to do a quick hotfix for `master`, which resulted in commit `L`.

(The branch names, at the far right, hold the raw hash IDs of the actual commits.  The letters stand in for these hash IDs, and each commit points backwards, to its predecessor, by storing the raw hash IDs of those predecessor commits.)

Now that we have commit `L`, we'd like to update our changes to be based on `K` instead of `H`.  To do that, we get Git to "copy" each commit, `I` and `J` and `K`, to come after `L` and to be based on the snapshot *in* `L`.  The final result of this rebase will look like this:

```
             I'-J'-K'  <-- feature
            /
...--G--H--L   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K   [abandoned]
```

where `I'` is our copy of `I`, `J'` is our copy of `J`, and `K'` is our copy of `K`.  The new commits have the same *changes* that the old commits had.  Their snapshots and parent commit hash IDs differ from the old commits—that's why they have different hash IDs and are different commits—but `git log -p` or `git show` will show the same *changes* as before.

#### Back to rebase

To make these copies and achieve the final rebase, Git must:

1. *list out* the raw hash IDs of the commits to be copied;
2. do a *detached HEAD* checkout of the target of the commit;
3. run `git cherry-pick` commands, or equivalents, for each commit to be copied;
4. move the branch name (with `git branch -f` or `git checkout -B`).

For a situation like the one in the sidebar, a single name—`master`—suffices both to figure out *what to copy* and to decide *where to put the copies*.

The *what to copy* part is a matter of running a `git rev-list`—`rev-list` is the internal plumbing variant of `git log`, mostly—with the equivalent of:

```
git rev-list master..feature
```

This lists out the correct hash IDs: the ones for commits `I`, `J`, and `K`.

The *where to put the copies* part is a matter of running `git checkout --detach master`.  That gets Git into the correct position to begin doing the cherry-pick operations.

(After this point, Git just does the cherry-picks and the final branch movement.)

But what if we *don't* want to copy *every* commit?

This scenario happens in many different ways, but here's one case:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- feature1
              \
               K--L   <-- feature2 (HEAD)
```

Having begun our work on feature 2, we now realize that we started, by mistake, at the end of `feature1`—with commit `J`—instead of at the end of `master` with commit `H`.

We'd like to transplant commits `K-L`, so as to get this:

```
          K'-L'  <-- feature2
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- feature1
              \
               K--L   [abandoned]
```

If we ran:

```
git rebase master
```

Git would run:

```
git rev-list master..feature2
```

which would list out commits `I-J-K-L`, because commits `I-J` **are** on `feature2`.  They're just on *both* `feature1` *and* `feature2`.  (Commits up through `H` are on *every* branch.)

**This means we need a way to separate out the *what to copy* part from the *where to put the copies* part.**  Adding `--onto` gives us this ability.

We run:

```
git rebase --onto master feature1
```

and now `git rebase` can use `git rev-list feature1..feature2` to list out the *commits to copy* part, and `git checkout --detach master` to get to the *where to put the copies* part.

#### Summary

That's really all there is to this.  We need `--onto` if and only if we need to separate *where to put the copies* from *what to copy*.  If we can use a single name or commit hash ID for both, we don't need `--onto`.  If we need two different names and/or hash IDs, we need `--onto`.  The documentation calls the `--onto` argument *`newbase`*.  If we omit `--onto`, then *`newbase`* and *`upstream`* are the same name/hash ID.

(In your case, you *left out* the *`upstream`* argument from your second rebase.  This caused Git to use its default: it picked the upstream *setting* of the current branch, and also added the `--fork-point` option if you're using Git 2.0 or later.)

Comment: When we see a very detailed and good answer on git, that's always a @torek one....